# Factory Method with unnecessary parameters

Tags: scala, factory, factory-pattern

Let’s say we have a factory trait

```
trait Factory {
  def createObject(paramA, paramB)
}
```

And now we have implementations of this Factory - FactoryV1 and FactoryV2 which are selected at runtime. While FactoryV2 uses both params to create object, FactoryV1 uses only paramA. So, when we call FactoryV1’s createObject method we pass an unnecessary parameter in paramB. How bad is passing an extra parameter? Some alternatives:

1. One way to improve upon it is to have paramB as a Scala Option, and depending on the factory being used, we pass `None` for FactoryV1.createObject and `Some` for FactoryV2.createObject.
2. Another alternative would be to have two methods in the base trait, one with just paramA and another with both parameters. Depending on the factory being used (V1 or V2), we call the appropriate method with 1/2 parameters (I don’t see a very clean way of doing this though).

What are other alternatives? I am inclined towards having a single factory method with Option parameters for those params that are not needed in all implementations of the factory.

Essentially what do we do when Factory implementations don't need all parameters of the Factory method?

Comment: You can use default value for the second parameter. Then you can call your method with just the first parameter. refer: http://alvinalexander.com/scala/scala-functions-named-default-arguments-parameters-methods

Comment: Overloading is a common solution to this problem, although you don't want that. The first overload can simply call the second overload with a `None` value, for convenience.

Comment: I vote for default parameter for the second param

Answer (score 0):

I'd say it all depends on how you want to handle the absence of second parameter where you require one.

```
val factory: Factory = new FactoryV2 // this is the one that needs both params to create an object

// Assuming signature createObject(param1, param2 = default)
// if you use default parameter, is it ok to create an object with default value? THis may be difficult to notice.
factory.createObject(param1)

// Assuming signature createObject(param1, Option[param2])    
// Is it ok to fail when second param not supplied?
factory.createObject(param1, None)
```

Choose your solution based on desired semantics.